# how to detect if the drop down menu is shown above or below the spinner in android?

Tags: android, spinner

I m working on design were spinner looks custom 
what i want is when spinner popup drop down below the spinner i want to used 
popupbackground image different and when it popup above the spinner i want to use popup background different

here is my Xml code:

```
 <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
    android:popupBackground="@drawable/spinnerbottombg"
    android:overlapAnchor="false"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"

    />
```

now question is how do i know spinner open the dropdown list above or below it

Comment: Are you asking how to apply custom style in spinner? or how to tell if the drop down menu is shown above or below the spinner? Clarify because your title is confusing

Comment: how to detect if the drop down menu is shown above or below the spinner?

Comment: use android:spinnerMode="dialog" in your xml file

Comment: android:spinnerMode="dialog" it wont  work  because popup should should be like dropdown only

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I dig deep in the PopupWindow and found that your requirement could be achieved by

> StateListDrawable

Following codes will explain everything-

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context="com.mmbarno.dummyalertdialog.MainActivity">

   <Spinner
       android:id="@+id/spinner"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
       android:overlapAnchor="false"
       android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**popup_bg_above.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="rectangle">
   <solid android:color="#FF4081" />
</shape>
```

**popup_bg_below.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="rectangle">
   <solid android:color="#3F51B5" />
</shape>
```

Lastly in **MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    spinner.setPopupBackgroundDrawable(getPopupBg());
    populateSpinner();
}

private void populateSpinner() {
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.planets_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private StateListDrawable getPopupBg() {
    StateListDrawable states = new StateListDrawable();
    int identifier = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("state_above_anchor", "attr", "android");
    states.addState(new int[] {identifier}, ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.popup_bg_below));
    states.addState(new int[]{}, ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.popup_bg_above));
    return states;
}
```

Hope your requirement will be fulfilled. I have tested it in different scenarios along with ScrollView. And it perfectly works.

[image: Popup Below]

[image: Popup Above]

Comment: @Andreyua I have given all source codes. You just need to put an string-array (planets_array) in strings.xml and run this code. Hope it will work.

Comment: Ok, what next. How determine, "get current state or something"?

Comment: @Andreyua Not actually. PopupWindow handle itself during setting background. Follow up https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html and specially "setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable background)" method. Hope you will understand the mechanism clearly.

Comment: Thanks, really appreciated

Comment: @Nawaf If this answer is as you required then please accept it.